# Парсинг html страницы , вывод в json

Tags: python, python-3.x

первый раз пытаюсь спрасить данные , появился вопрос , у меня есть загруженные html страницы , я хочу написать алгоритм который превращает данные со страниц в такой формат 
[
   {
    "address":"Белгород, Пугачева,5",
    "latlon":"[44.983268, 41.096873]",
    "name":"Мебель Шара",
    "phones": ["8 800 551 06 10"],
    "working_hours":["Без выходных 10-20"]
   }
]

Проблема заключается в том что город находится в отдельном теге и я не знаю как корректно добавлять города к адресу . https://www.mebelshara.ru/contacts - ссылка на саму страницу

Фрагмент кода html страницы, на ней это к примеру Белгород и он должен присутствовать в каждом адресе своих магазинов.

**mebelshara.html**

```
    </script></head><body><div id="modern-app"><header id="header"><ms-head-banner></ms-head-banner><!--<div class="preheader-banner" style="background-color: "><a href=""><img src="https://www.mebelshara.ru/themes/shara/assets/images/modern/banners" alt=""></a></div>--><div class="header"><div><div class="hamburger-btn js-m-menu-show"><span></span></div><div class="logo"><a href="https://www.mebelshara.ru" title="Мебель Шара"><img src="https://www.mebelshara.ru/themes/shara/assets/images/modern/logo.png" alt="Мебель Шара"></a></div></div><div><div class="geo"><div class="geo-label js-geo-label"><ms-location-btn id="b48c8769-0d2b-11ea-b95d-0242ac110002" name="Смоленск"></ms-location-btn></div></div><div class="search-wrap"><ms-search></ms-search></div><div class="phone-wrap"><a href="tel:78005510610" class="phone"><span class="phone-num zphone">8 800 551 06 10</span></a></div></div><div><div class="services-buttons"><ms-city-list-button><div class="substrate"></div></ms-city-list-button><ms-auth-button><div class="substrate"></div></ms-auth-button><ms-favorite-list-button><div class="substrate"></div></ms-favorite-list-button><ms-cart-button><div class="substrate"></div></ms-cart-button></div></div></div></header><div class="main-navigation"><div class="side-menu animate mini"><div class="menu-list-wrap"><div class="menu-list"><ul id="nav"><li class=""><a href="/catalog/divany-i-kresla" data-cat-id="1"><span class="icon icon--divan"></span><span class="item-name">Диваны и кресла</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/spalni" data-cat-id="2"><span class="icon icon--spalni"></span><span class="item-name">Мебель для спальни</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/mebel-dlya-kukhni" data-cat-id="3"><span class="icon icon--kitchen"></span><span class="item-name">Мебель для кухни</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/mebel-dlya-gostinoy" data-cat-id="4"><span class="icon icon--gostinaya"></span><span class="item-name">Мебель для гостиной</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/detskie" data-cat-id="5"><span class="icon icon--detskie"></span><span class="item-name">Мебель для детской</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/shkafy-i-prikhozhyye" data-cat-id="6"><span class="icon icon--shkafy-i-prikhozhyye"></span><span class="item-name">Шкафы и прихожие</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/stoly-i-stulya" data-cat-id="7"><span class="icon icon--stoly-i-stulya"></span><span class="item-name">Столы и стулья</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/komody" data-cat-id="8"><span class="icon icon--komody"></span><span class="item-name">Комоды</span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/catalog/tovary-dlya-doma" data-cat-id="9"><span class="icon icon--dlya-doma"></span><span class="item-name">Товары для дома</span></a></li><li><a href="/shares" data-cat-id="300"><span class="icon icon--shares"></span><span class="item-name">Акции</span><span class="item-chip"><span>7</span></span></a></li></ul></div><div class="bottom-nav"><div><a href="/contacts" class="ln-black">Адреса салонов</a></div><div><a href="/dostavka-i-sborka" class="ln-black">Доставка</a></div><div><a href="/oplata" class="ln-black">Оплата</a></div><div><a href="/obmen-i-vozvrat" class="ln-black">Обмен и возврат</a></div></div></div><ms-navigation-menu></ms-navigation-menu></div><ms-mobile-menu geo-city-id="b48c8769-0d2b-11ea-b95d-0242ac110002" geo-city-name="Смоленск"></ms-mobile-menu></div><div class="services-container"><nav class="services-nav"><div class="services-nav-title">Сервис</div><ul class="nav-list"><li class=""><a href="/dostavka-i-sborka">Доставка и Сборка</a></li><li class=""><a href="/oplata">Оплата</a></li><li class="selected"><a href="/contacts">Адреса салонов</a></li><li class=""><a href="/garantiya">Гарантия</a></li><li class=""><a href="/obmen-i-vozvrat">Обмен и Возврат</a></li><li class=""><a href="/share-conditions">Бонусная программа</a></li><li class=""><a href="/rassrochka_kredit">Рассрочка</a></li><li class=""><a href="/otzyvy">Отзывы</a></li><li class=""><a href="/voprosy">Вопросы и ответы</a></li><li class=""><a href="/kontaktnye-dannye">Контактные данные</a></li><li class=""><a href="/promocode-conditions">Условия использования промокодов</a></li></ul></nav><div class="services-content-wrap content-overlay"><div class="services-content"><div class="container"><ul class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="https://www.mebelshara.ru">Главная</a></li><li class="breadcrumb-item active">Адреса салонов</li></ul><h1>Адреса салонов</h1><div class="address"><div class="city-list js-city-list"><div class="city-item"><div class="expand-block top-border"><div class="expand-block-header js-ex-btn" data-close-all>
<h4 class="js-city-name">Белгород</h4><div class="expand-block-header-btn"></div></div><div class="expand-block-content"><div class="expand-block-content-inner"><div class="city-shops"><div class="shop-list"><div class="shop-list-item"
                                     data-shop-name="ТЦ Европа"
                                     data-shop-address="Пугачева, 5"
                                                                      data-shop-mode1="Без выходных:"
                                     data-shop-mode2="10:00 - 20:00"
                                     data-shop-latitude="50.59084"
                                     data-shop-longitude="36.59734"
                                     data-shop-number="1"
                                     data-shop-discount-center="0"
                                ><div class="shop-name">ТЦ Европа</div><div class="shop-address">Пугачева, 5</div><div class="shop-weekends">Время работы: 10:00 - 20:00</div><div class="shop-work-time">Без выходных:</div></div><div class="shop-list-item"
                                     data-shop-name="ТЦ Атлас"
                                     data-shop-address="Щорса, 8 Д"
                                                                      data-shop-mode1="Без выходных:"
                                     data-shop-mode2="10:00 - 20:00"
                                     data-shop-latitude="50.58516"
                                     data-shop-longitude="36.565457"
                                     data-shop-number="2"
                                     data-shop-discount-center="0"
                                ><div class="shop-name">ТЦ Атлас</div><div class="shop-address">Щорса, 8 Д</div><div class="shop-weekends">Время работы: 10:00 - 20:00</div><div class="shop-work-time">Без выходных:</div></div><div class="shop-list-item"
                                     data-shop-name="ТЦ РИО"
                                     data-shop-address="Богдана Хмельницкого пр-т, 164"
                                                                      data-shop-mode1="Без выходных:"
                                     data-shop-mode2="10:00 - 22:00"
                                     data-shop-latitude="50.64208"
                                     data-shop-longitude="36.572086"
                                     data-shop-number="3"
                                     data-shop-discount-center="0"
                                ><div class="shop-name">ТЦ РИО</div><div class="shop-address">Богдана Хмельницкого пр-т, 164</div><div class="shop-weekends">Время работы: 10:00 - 22:00</div><div class="shop-work-time">Без выходных:</div></div><div class="shop-list-item"
                                     data-shop-name="ТЦ Стройдепо"
                                     data-shop-address="п.Северный, Березовая, 1 Б"
                                                                      data-shop-mode1="Без выходных:"
                                     data-shop-mode2="10:00 - 20:00"
                                     data-shop-latitude="50.65852"
                                     data-shop-longitude="36.562627"
                                     data-shop-number="4"
                                     data-shop-discount-center="0"
                            >
```

**parser**

```
def parsing():
    form = []
    form2 = []
    html1 = open('mebelshara.html').read()
    html2 = open('tuiru.html').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')
    h4 = soup.find_all('h4', {'class': 'js-city-name'})
    div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'shop-list-item'})
    for h in h4:
        form.append({'address': h.next})
    for d in div:
        form2.append({'address':  d.get('data-shop-address'),
                      'latlon': [d.get('data-shop-latitude') +
                                 ", " + d.get('data-shop-longitude')],
                      'name': 'Мебель Шара', 'phones': ['8 800 551 06 10'],
                      'working_hours': [d.get('data-shop-mode1') + " " + d.get('data-shop-mode2')],
                      })
```

Comment: Вам нужно обрабатывать каждый блок `<div class="city-item">` Извлекая город и для всех магазинов добавляя это значение.

Comment: Немного подправил ответ. Заменил класс на функцию (класс там нафиг не нужен)

Comment: Спасибо, за конструктивный ответ!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что-то похожее, с элементом авторской фантазии и без телефонов, чет не нашел я их на этом сайте. Если вывод не совсем такой как Вам нужен, напишите, поправлю или можете допилить сами. Так мне показалось юзабильней:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from requests import Session
from bs4.element import Tag
from pprint import pprint
import json


def make_dict(city_name: str, shop: Tag) -> dict:
    return {
        'address': city_name + ', ' + shop['data-shop-address'],
        'latitude': shop['data-shop-latitude'],
        'longitude': shop['data-shop-longitude'],
        'name': shop['data-shop-name'],
        'working_hours': [shop['data-shop-mode1'], shop['data-shop-mode2']]
    }


def city_shops(city_div: Tag):
    city_tag: Tag
    city_tag = city_div.find('h4', {'class': 'js-city-name'}).extract()
    city_name = city_tag.text

    shops = city_div.find_all('div', {'class': 'shop-list-item'})

    return [make_dict(city_name, shop) for shop in shops]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_url = 'https://www.mebelshara.ru/contacts'
    with Session() as session:
        soup = Soup(session.get(base_url).content, 'html.parser')
        cities = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'city-item'})

        shop_list = []

        for city in cities:
            shop_list += city_shops(city)

        pprint(shop_list)

# [{'address': 'Белгород, Пугачева, 5',
#   'latitude': '50.59084',
#   'longitude': '36.59734',
#   'name': 'ТЦ Европа',
#   'working_hours': ['Без выходных:', '10:00 - 20:00']},
#  {'address': 'Белгород, Щорса, 8 Д',
#   'latitude': '50.58516',
#   'longitude': '36.565457',
#   'name': 'ТЦ Атлас',
#   'working_hours': ['Без выходных:', '10:00 - 20:00']},
#   
#   ...
#   
#   {'address': 'Щекино, Лукашина, 1 А',
#   'latitude': '54.01587',
#   'longitude': '37.508948',
#   'name': 'ТЦ БУМ',
#   'working_hours': ['Без выходных:', '09:00 - 19:00']},
#  {'address': 'Алексин, Тульская, 136 Д',
#   'latitude': '54.50809',
#   'longitude': '37.11640',
#   'name': 'ТЦ Слобода',
#   'working_hours': ['Без выходных:', '09:00 - 19:00']}]
```

Если `pprint` заменить на `json.dumps` то получится следующее:

```
j = json.dumps(shop_list, ensure_ascii=False)

print(j)

# [{"address": "Белгород, Пугачева, 5", "latitude": "50.59084", "longitude": "36.59734", "name": "ТЦ Европа", "working_hours": ["Без выходных:", "10:00 - 20:00"]}, ... {"address": "Алексин, Тульская, 136 Д", "latitude": "54.50809", "longitude": "37.11640", "name": "ТЦ Слобода", "working_hours": ["Без выходных:", "09:00 - 19:00"]}]
```